# Using C# System.Diagnostics.Process to run git command line with basic authentication succeeds but returns error

Tags: c#, git, ssh, tfs, process

I have a C# console app that fires git cli commands en masse.  I use `System.Diagnostics.Process` and it returns an error even though the command succeeds.  I would ignore this error except for git itself is kind of confused.

For example, if I do a `push` cli using `Process` object, the push succeeds, `Process` returns an error message, and if I go to git bash and do a `git status` command, it says it is 1 commit ahead of remote repository.  If I open the remote repository (TFS in this case), my commit is indeed there.

I simply issue a `git pull` from git bash and get a 'Everything up-to-date' message and now everything is 'ok'.  Note, if I do a `git pull` via C# `Process`, it does **not** fix/correct the status mismatch in my local repository.

Here is my `Process` code:

```
public string[] CallGitCommandLine( string repoPath, string command )
{
    var p = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo( @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" );
    
    // command: pull https://{user}:{password}@tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/HRS2/_git/HRS%20BTR%20-%20ess.evolution.nexgen
    
    p.Arguments = command;
    p.WorkingDirectory = repoPath;
    p.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // Set ProcessStartInfo 'runas' to current user/creds
    p.UserName = Environment.UserName;
    p.Password = new System.Security.SecureString();
    
    foreach( var c in localPassword.ToCharArray() )
    {
        p.Password.AppendChar( c );
    }
    
    using( var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process() )
    {
        proc.StartInfo = p;
        proc.Start();

        var output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        var error = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        proc.WaitForExit();
        
        var logRaw = string.IsNullOrEmpty( output ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( error )
            ? error.Split( '\n' ).ToArray()
            : output.Split( '\n' ).ToArray();
        
        proc.Close();
    
        return logRaw;
    }
}
```

When I issue a `pull` command, I get the following from `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`:

> fatal: Failed to write item to store. [0x520] fatal: A specified logon
> session does not exist. It may already have been terminated From
> [https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/{..company](https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/%7B..company) url..}
>
> - branch           HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

When I issue a `push` command, I get the following from `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`:

> fatal: Failed to write item to store. [0x520] fatal: A specified logon
> session does not exist. It may already have been terminated To
> [https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/{..company](https://tfs.acsgs.com/tfs/PDSI/%7B..company) url..}
> e12fb1b..d4c4efa main -> main

Is there a way to make these `pull` and `push` commands work from a C# console app?

**Update**
Note that when I get these errors, `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` returns the error, but `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` returns 'valid' messages.

For example, when I do a `pull`, `StandardOutput` returns *Already up to date.*  **But**, when I do a `push`, `StandardOutput` is just blank.

**Update**: If I try doing a `push` while using SSH protocol, simply `git push {origin} {branch}` with the `remote.{origin}.url` configured to a SSH endpoint, I get the following from `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`:

> To bitbucket.org:{company repo}.git
> e12fb1b..d4c4efa  main -> main

Is the original problem that my SSH key is being loaded (via Windows? Terminal?) and then used/conflicts with url to TFS commands from my console app?  Note, I have SSH for bitbucket, but I do **not** have SSH for TFS.

Comment: You have to proc.WaitForExit(); before reading standardoutput and standarderror.

Comment: Same result if I move those lines below `WaitForExit()`.